# Isomorphism between the class group and Picard group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, sheaf-theory

Here is from Vakil's FOAG,Exercise 13.1.M,part (d),page 374:[image]

where $K$ is a number field and $\mathcal O_K$ is the ring of integers in $K$.The main difficulty is to show that every invertible sheaf on $Spec\mathcal O_K$ comes from certain fractional ideal. My thought is using the structure theorem for f.g. module over Dedekind domain.But I don't know if it is necessary to quote such a theorem.So can you give me some hints?

Comment: An invertible sheaf on a DD is coherent, so it corresponds to a module. Since it is also invertible, that module is f.g. and hence a fractional ideal. Once you know that, combine with the fact that the tensor product of fractional ideals is the same as the product and you're basically done. I am not sure what you mean about the structure theorem for f.g. modules over a DD.

Comment: I get it,thank you.